# Why is this method not synchronised?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created a REST controller (in Spring Boot 2.2.2) that calls an "Invokable" service class, like so:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("service")
public class ServiceController {

    private Set<Invokable> services;

    @Autowired
    public ServiceController(Set<Invokable> services) {
        this.services = services;
    }

    @GetMapping("invoke/{service}")
    public void invoke(@PathVariable("service") String service) throws InterruptedException {
        val invokable = services.stream().filter(c -> AopUtils.getTargetClass(c).getName().equals(service)).findFirst();
        invokable.get().invoke();
    }
}
```

The `Invokable` interface method is marked `Async`:

```java
public interface Invokable {

    @Async("taskExecutor")
    void invoke();
}
```

One of the implementations looks like this:

```java
@Service
@Transactional
public class EventListener implements Invokable {

    private static boolean RUNNING = false;

    private EventService eventService;

    private List<EventProcessor> processors;

    @Autowired
    public EventListener(EventService eventService,
                         List<EventProcessor> processors) {
        this.eventService = eventService;
        this.processors = processors;
    }

    @Override
    public void invoke() {
        if (!RUNNING) {

            RUNNING = true;

            [...]

            RUNNING = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Above you can see that I have implemented a custom synchronization mechanism by locking the method down using the `RUNNING` boolean. This works fine, but I'd rather not have to implement this myself.

Previously I had tried (via `lombok`):

```java
@Override
@Synchronized
public void invoke() {
  ...
}
```

and

```java
@Override
public synchronized void invoke() {
  ...
}
```

and

```java
@Override
public void invoke() {
  synchronized(this) {
    ...
  }
}
```

However, all of the above appear to allow more than one simultaneous invokation of the method.

Have I miss understood what `synchronized` is used for?
Is there a cleaner way of achieving the above without implementing the mechanism myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`synchronized` prevents concurrent invocations. But that doesn't mean that an invocation made while one is running will be discarded and ignored. It means it will block, waiting, until the previous one has finished, and then execute.

Your code doesn't synchronize anything. It only ignores invocations that are made while one is running, which is very different. And it does it in a non-thread-safe way: two separate threads invoking the method concurrently might see the same value of the boolean, and both execute the method concurrently. Even worse: the change to the boolean made in one thread might not be visible in another thread.

You would need to properly use an AtomicBoolean to do what you're doing in a thread-safe way.

Comment: Would you mind giving an example of a `AtomicBoolean` implementation?

Comment: `if (running.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            // ...
            running.set(false);
        }`. And it shouldn't be static: your bean is a singleton anyway.

Comment: Thanks, and would you recommend this as an appropriate solution?

Comment: I have no idea of what you really want to achieve. Do you actually want to discard calls while another one is running or not?

Comment: Yes. I want to completely disregard calls from all other threads whilst the method is currently executing.

Comment: Then do that, yes.